# Proof that $\nabla \times E = 0$ using Stoke's theorem

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, vector-fields, calculus

One way that Jackson proves that $\nabla \times E = 0$ is the following:

$$ F = q E $$

$$ W = - \int_A^B F \cdot dl = - q \int_A^B E \cdot dl = q \int_A^B \nabla \phi \cdot dl = 
 q \int_A^B d \phi = q(\phi_B - \phi_A) $$

so $\int_A^B E \cdot dl = -(\phi_B - \phi_A)$ therefore $\oint_A^B E \cdot dl = 0$

Then using Stoke's theorem $\int (\nabla \times E) \cdot \hat{n} da = 0$ which implies $\nabla \times E=0$.

1. Isn't the last line true only if $\nabla \times E \geq 0$?
2. How does $\nabla \phi \cdot dl = d\phi$ in general? I can only see how this is true if $dl = dx \hat{x}$ or similarly for $y$ or $z$.
3. The initial integration for $W$ is over a path in space (w.r.t $x,y,z$), yet at the end we are integrating w.r.t $\phi$? How does that even make sense?

I was split on whether to post this here or on the Math site. I figured maybe the answer to my first question could only be due to the specifics of $\nabla \times E$, since it seems like Jackson is instantiating $\int f(x) dx = 0 \implies f(x) = 0$, but this isn't guaranteed unless we already know $f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: If you already are able to make the substitution $\vec E = \vec \nabla \phi$ then immediately you have $\vec \nabla \times \vec E=0$. This is because $\vec \nabla \times \vec \nabla f = 0$, where $f$ is any function of space and time .

Answer (score 0):

> ...
> Then using Stoke's theorem $\int (\nabla \times E) \cdot \hat{n} da = 0$ which implies $\nabla \times E=0$.

> 1. Isn't the last line true only if $\nabla \times E \geq 0$?

No. It isn't. The closed loop path is arbitrary.

Also, you don't need Stokes' theorem. You already have $\vec E = -\vec \nabla \phi$, so:
$$
\vec \nabla \times \vec E = -\vec \nabla \times \vec \nabla \phi
$$
$$
=\hat e^{(i)} \epsilon_{ijk}\nabla_j\nabla_k\phi = 0\;,
$$
by the symmetry of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ (totally antisymmetric in all indices) and $\nabla_j \nabla_k \phi$ (totally symmetric in all indices).

> 2. How does $\nabla \phi \cdot dl = d\phi$ in general? I can only see how this is true if $dl = dx \hat{x}$ or similarly for $y$ or $z$.

Or similarly, in general:
$$
d\phi = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}dx
+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}dy
+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}dz
$$
$$
=\vec \nabla\phi\cdot d\vec{\ell}
$$

> 3. The initial integration for $W$ is over a path in space (w.r.t $x,y,z$), yet at the end we are integrating w.r.t $\phi$? How does that even make sense?

Because you changed integration variables from $\vec{\ell}$ to $\phi$.

This, again, is basically the why we introduce an integral in terms of the anti-derivative. It the analog of the 1-d example:
$$
f(x) = \frac{dF}{dx}
$$
and
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx f(x) = \int_{F(x_1)}^{F(x_2)} dF = F_2 - F_1\;.
$$

---

All these question seem to be questions about basic or intermediate vector calculus. I suggest you find an intermediate level undergraduate textbook on vector calculus and refresh your memory as to these fundamental concepts.

Comment: 1) I get that you can prove it that way too. Jackson also has this in his book. That is besides my first point. My question is about the validity of the proof using Stoke's theorem. The last inference doesn't seem valid to me. And do you know why my question got downvoted?
3) Yes, but you changed the bounds from $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $F(x_1)$ and $F(x_2)$. Jackson did not do that.

Comment: Your question is a homework or check-my-work type question. Your question a compound question with a bunch of sub-questions. You can find out more about what might be wrong here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't know you are right about what Jackson did or not. You just write "A" and "B." In the first case "A" and "B" presumably means integrating from $\vec r_A$ to $\vec r_B$ in some coordinate system and in the second case from $\phi(\vec r_A)$ to $\phi(\vec r_B)$. Jackson probably means to imply that the points "A" and "B" are independent of the particular coordinates or integration variable.

Comment: Also your question is not really a physics question, it is a bunch of questions about vector calculus.

Comment: Well it's not a homework problem, it's an example in Jackson's book. I literally wrote what Jackson wrote. He just uses A and B. I was split on whether to post this here or on the Math site. I figured maybe the answer to my first question could only be due to the specifics of $\nabla \times E$, since $\int f(x) dx = 0 \implies f(x) = 0$ isn't guaranteed unless $f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: "Well it's not a homework problem..." Well, I didn't say it was a homework problem. I said it was a homework *type* question. It doesn't matter if it is *literally* homework or not. Also, I answered your first question in the edit to my post. The answer to your first question is no, it does not require $\nabla \times E \geq 0$.

Comment: Ok I edited it. Can you please explain more though? Like how does the closed path being arbitrary allow us to conclude that the integrand is 0. I am only familiar with the mathematical theorem that I put in my last comment, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138609/discussion-between-hft-and-ngc1300).